# Why does this code give an "Each child in a list should have a unique 'key' prop" error?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

If I replace the fragment (<> </>) with a div and give it a key I no longer get the error but that also screws up my button group.  Each of these elements has a unique key and the fragment should not be a dom element so why this error?  Any suggestions on a solution?

```
{["long", "short", "out", "none"].map(stance =>
           <>
               <input type="radio" className="btn-check" id={stance} key={stance}
               autoComplete="off" checked={options.stance === stance} disabled={options.auto}/>
               <label key={`${stance}label`} className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" htmlFor={stance}>{stance}</label>
           </>
)}
```

Just to close this out I think the quickest/easiest solution was the following:

```
{["long", "short", "out", "none"].map(stance =>
           <React.Fragment key={stance}>
               <input type="radio" className="btn-check" id={stance} 
               autoComplete="off" checked={options.stance === stance} disabled={options.auto}/>
               <label className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" htmlFor={stance}>{stance}</label>
           <React.Fragment/>
)}
```

Comment: the key needs to be part of the fragment, not something within it

Comment: Why is that given fragments aren't supposed to be DOM elements?  And if that's the solution, how is it done?  A key prop isn't accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this from the react documentation:

https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#keyed-fragments

```
<React.Fragment key={your key}>
    {your code}
</React.Fragment>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked!  Apparently the abbreviated fragment tag won't accept a prop, but the spelled out one will.  Perfect solution!

Comment: Please don’t post a link only answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to use a div just make a component that you can map and still keep the jsx like so.

```
function MyInput({stance}){
   return(
     <>
    <input type="radio" className="btn-check" id={stance} 
               autoComplete="off" checked={options.stance === stance} disabled={options.auto}/>
               <label className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" htmlFor={stance}>{stance}</label>
    </> 
  )
}
```

Then for you map you can do this.

```
{["long", "short", "out", "none"].map((stance, i) =>
          <MyInput stance={stance} key={i}/>
)}
```

Comment: I expect this would have worked too.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @BaronYoung I forgot to remove the key from your input and label when I first posted so just make sure you take those out as they are no longer needed :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 {["long", "short", "out", "none"].map((stance,index) =>
       <>
           <input type="radio" className="btn-check" id={stance} key={index}
           autoComplete="off" checked={options.stance === stance} disabled={options.auto}/>
           <label key={`${stance}label`} className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" htmlFor={stance}>{stance}</label>
       </>
```

)}

in key use index instead of stance ,the index will come from map(stance,index)